# How to select conditional rows with groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I want to select rows with groupby conditions.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dftest = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Feb',np.nan,'Air','Flow','Feb',
                            'Beta','Cat','Feb','Beta','Air'],
                       'B':['s','s','t','s','t','s','t','t','t','t'],
                       'C':[5,4,3,2,1,7,6,5,4,3],
                       'D':[4,np.nan,3,np.nan,2,
                            np.nan,2,3,np.nan,7]})
def filcols3(df,dd):
    if df.iloc[0]['D']==dd:
        return df
dd=4    
grp=dftest.groupby('B').apply(filcols3,dd)
```

the result of grp is:

```
         A  B  C    D
B                   
s 0   Feb  s  5  4.0
  1   NaN  s  4  NaN
  3  Flow  s  2  NaN
  5  Beta  s  7  NaN
```

this is what I want.

while if I use the following code(part 2)

```
def filcols3(df,dd):
    if df.iloc[0]['D']<=dd:
        return df
dd=3
```

the result is:

```
       A    B    C    D
0   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   Air    t  3.0  3.0
3   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4   Feb    t  1.0  2.0
5   NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6   Cat    t  6.0  2.0
7   Feb    t  5.0  3.0
8  Beta    t  4.0  NaN
9   Air    t  3.0  7.0
```

I'm surprise for this result, I mean to get

```
      A  B  C    D
2   Air  t  3  3.0
4   Feb  t  1  2.0
6   Cat  t  6  2.0
7   Feb  t  5  3.0
8  Beta  t  4  NaN
9   Air  t  3  7.0
```

what's wrong with the code of part 2? how to get the final result I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apply`'s behaviour is a little non-intuitive here, but if the idea is to filter out entire groups based on a specific condition per group, you can use `GroupBy.transform` and get a mask to filter `df`:

```
df[df.groupby('B')['D'].transform('first') <= 3]

      A  B  C    D
2  Air   t  3  3.0
4  Feb   t  1  2.0
6  Cat   t  6  2.0
7  Feb   t  5  3.0
8  Beta  t  4 NaN 
9  Air   t  3  7.0
```

Or, fixing your code,

```
df[df.groupby('B')['D'].transform(lambda x: x.values[0] <= 3)]

      A  B  C    D
2  Air   t  3  3.0
4  Feb   t  1  2.0
6  Cat   t  6  2.0
7  Feb   t  5  3.0
8  Beta  t  4 NaN 
9  Air   t  3  7.0
```

Answer (score 4):

May Check with `filter`

```
dftest.groupby('B').filter(lambda x : any(x['D'].head(1)<=3))
Out[538]: 
      A  B  C    D
2   Air  t  3  3.0
4   Feb  t  1  2.0
6   Cat  t  6  2.0
7   Feb  t  5  3.0
8  Beta  t  4  NaN
9   Air  t  3  7.0
```

Or ***without*** `groupby` `drop_duplicates`

```
s=df.drop_duplicates('B').D<=3
df[df.B.isin(df.loc[s.index,'B'][s])]
Out[550]: 
      A  B  C    D
2   Air  t  3  3.0
4   Feb  t  1  2.0
6   Cat  t  6  2.0
7   Feb  t  5  3.0
8  Beta  t  4  NaN
9   Air  t  3  7.0
```